# Javascript - Code is duplicating more than what I need

Tags: javascript

TRYING TO ADD NEW METHOD

I'm trying to add two cards each to the player/dealer hands, but when i log it:

```
[ { suit: '♠', value: 'A', points: 11 } ]
[ { suit: '♠', value: 'A', points: 11 },
  { suit: '♦', value: 10, points: 10 } ]
```

Why am I getting 3 objects returned instead of 2?

```
const dealRandomCard = () => {
 return deckOfCards.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * 
deckOfCards.length), 1)[0];
}

// console.log(dealRandomCard());


for (let i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
 playerHand.push(dealRandomCard());
 dealerHand.push(dealRandomCard());
  console.log(playerHand);
// console.log(dealerHand);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  playerHand.push(dealRandomCard());
  dealerHand.push(dealRandomCard());
  console.log(playerHand);
}
```

You loop should be `for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++)` instead of `for (let i = 0; i <= 2; i++)`

That cost you an extra iteration since you go from `0` to `2` which is a length of `3` ... `[0,1,2] = 3`.

Also this: `return deckOfCards.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * deckOfCards.length), 1)[0];`

If this gets you more than 1 you end up with 3 since your `deck` contains 1 + an array of 2 more as pointed out nicely by `@Ricky Mo`

Comment: still prints out 3 objects like above.

Comment: Added more details.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `console.log()` in every iteration. You print once everytime you add one card. Your given output is actually two arrays, printed from two iterations. The first has 1 card, the second has 2 cards. Look at the `[` and `]` carefully.

First iteration:

```
[ { suit: '♠', value: 'A', points: 11 } ]
```

Second iteration:

```
[ { suit: '♠', value: 'A', points: 11 },
{ suit: '♦', value: 10, points: 10 } ]
```

Comment: Yes, good call. It was printing twice, I needed to log it outside the for loop.